# Navigating relay.js app with RelayRouter throwing Invalid State Change error

Tags: reactjs, react-router, graphql, relayjs

I'm writing a relay.js app, and I'm using [react-relay-router](https://github.com/relay-tools/react-router-relay) for routing. Routing works, but I believe it is exposing a misunderstanding on my part of how to organize query fragments across different views.

routes defined in **app.js**

```js
const rootComponent =
  (<RelayRouter history={hashHistory}>
    <Route path="/"
      component={App}
      queries={ViewerQueries}
      onReadyStateChange={this.handleStateChange}
    >
      <IndexRoute
        component={Dashboard}
        queries={ViewerQueries}
      />
      <Route
        path="/org_setup"
        component={OrgSetup}
        queries={ViewerQueries}
      />
      <Route
        path="/admin/data_models"
        component={DataModelList}
        queries={ViewerQueries}
      />
    </Route>
  </RelayRouter>);
ReactDOM.render(rootComponent, mountNode);
```

query fragment declaration in **DataModelList.js**

```js
export default Relay.createContainer(DataModelList, {
  fragments: {
    viewer: () => Relay.QL`
      fragment on User {
        dataModels(first: 10) {
          edges {
            node {
              id,
              name,
              isAuthority,
              categories(first: 10) {
                edges {
                  node {
                    id,
                    name,
                    tags(first: 10) {
                      edges {
                        node {
                          id,
                          code,
                          label,
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              adapter {
                categories(first: 10) {
                  edges {
                    node {
                      id,
                      name,
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
      }
    `,
  },
});
```

query fragment in **OrgSetup.js**

```js
export default Relay.createContainer(OrgSetup, {
  fragments: {
    viewer: () => Relay.QL`
      fragment on User {
        dataModels(first: 10) {
          edges {
            node {
              id,
              name,
              isAuthority,
              categories(first: 10) {
                edges {
                  node {
                    id,
                    name,
                    tags(first: 10) {
                      edges {
                        node {
                          id,
                          code,
                          label,
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
            }
          }
        },
      }
    `,
  },
});
```

When navigating between `DataModelList` and `OrgSetup` (in either direction) I see the following error in the console:

```
Server request for query `ViewerQueries` failed for the following reasons:

1. Cannot query field "node" on "Query".
   rQueries($id_0:ID!){node(id:$id_0){id,__typename,...F0}} fra

Warning: RelayReadyState: Invalid state change from 
{"aborted":false,"done":false,"error":{"source":{"data":null,"errors":
[{"message":"Cannot query field \"node\" on \"Query\".","locations":
[{"line":1,"column":32}]}]}},"ready":false,"stale":false}` to `{"error":
{"source":{"data":null,"errors":[{"message":"Cannot query field \"node\" on 
\"Query\".","locations":[{"line":1,"column":32}]}]}}}`.warning @ 
app.js:31567update @ app.js:39409onRejected @ app.js:39035tryCallOne @ 
app.js:30045(anonymous function) @ app.js:30131flush @ app.js:30279
```

I'm able to prevent this error from occurring by making the query fragments in the two views identical - specifically by adding the `adapter` fragment.

However, this feels wrong. They don't need to be identical (in fact they are somewhat intentionally bloated at the moment since this is a learning app for me), and other views will of course not share these data needs.

1. What is the best practice for keeping query declarations concise?
   Ideally I would have top level views only declare top level data
   requirements. Concretely, in my example view files I would request
   only the `viewer` and their `dataModels`, and then allow child
   components to express their needs, requesting any nested data (eg
   `categories`, `tags`, or `adapters` and their respective `categories`).
2. What does the `invalid state change` error really mean? I can see
   that it's satisfied by the queries matching exactly, but I can't
   imagine unrelated views are required to share query declarations. I
   suspect this is a byproduct of my doing something wrong elsewhere.

Thanks!

Comment: With respect to the `invalid state change` error: it looks like a second state change is getting flushed down without the proper state change properties (aborted, done, et cetera). I wonder where those are coming from. If you have time to make a repro case on the Relay Playground, we'd be happy to field an issue or a pull request. https://github.com/facebook/relay/blob/master/src/store/RelayReadyState.js#L57-L67

Comment: @steveluscher This error has gone away now that I have 1) included the logic for resolving an `adapter` in the `nodeInterface` and 2) set the `node` field on the root query. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the query changes (eg. due to a route transition, or a call to `setVariables()`) Relay will diff the query you're coming from and the query you're headed to, computing the minimal query to get you from A to B. In your case, Relay starts from the series of known records stored on the client (the already-fetched ones) and tries to fetch only the new fields on those exact records in an effort to build a complete picture of the world. These refetches rely on something called the [node interface](https://facebook.github.io/relay/graphql/objectidentification.htm#sec-Node-root-field).

Relay-compliant GraphQL servers must expose a root field called `node` that can fetch any record given a global ID. This field must take an `id` argument of type `GraphQLID!`.

For an example of how to build such a root field, see [this `graphql-js` example](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-relay-js#object-identification).

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation. This was exactly what I was doing wrong. I had defined a node interface but had stupidly forgotten to connect it to my query by way of a root `node` field.